# Duplicate Column Name error MySQL multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

UPDATE:

Here is my new query - I think this is written correctly, but I'm getting an error messages saying `Duplicate column name 'PART_KIT_ID'` --- the two subqueries are almost identical, just the joins are different... any ideas?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
, CASE WHEN b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> c.EQUIP_MDL_ID and b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> a.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID FLAG A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID and b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> a.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID FLAG B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID  and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = b.EQUIP_MDL_ID
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = c.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = d.PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
, CASE WHEN b.SECTION_ID <> c.SECTION_ID and b.SECTION_ID <> a.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.SECTION_ID = c.SECTION_ID and b.SECTION_ID <> a.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
 FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
 JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = b.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = b.EQUIP_MDL_ID
 JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = c.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = d.PART_KIT_ID 
  ) A ,
   (SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
   , CASE WHEN a.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> c.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID INSERTFLAG' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
   , a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
   , a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
   , a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
   , d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
   FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
   JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
   , CASE WHEN a.SECTION_ID <> c.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID INSERTFLAG' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
   , a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
   , a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
   , a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
   , d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
   FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
   JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID
   WHERE a.PART_KIT_ID IS NULL
   ) B
```

Original Question - how to join these two queries into one?

QUERY A

```
SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID, `PART_KIT_NAME`, `EQUIP_MDL`, `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`, `PART_KIT_DESC`, `Flag NameA`, `Flag NameB`
from (SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
, CASE WHEN b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> c.EQUIP_MDL_ID and b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> a.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID FLAG A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID and b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> a.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID FLAG B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID  and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = b.EQUIP_MDL_ID
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = c.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = d.PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
, CASE WHEN b.SECTION_ID <> c.SECTION_ID and b.SECTION_ID <> a.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.SECTION_ID = c.SECTION_ID and b.SECTION_ID <> a.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = b.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = b.EQUIP_MDL_ID
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = c.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = d.PART_KIT_ID 
) a
```

QUERY B

```
SELECT b.PART_KIT_ID, `PART_KIT_NAME`, `EQUIP_MDL`, `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`, `PART_KIT_DESC`, `Flag NameA`, `Flag NameB`
FROM (SELECT c.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
, CASE WHEN a.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> c.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID INSERTFLAG' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID`
, CASE WHEN a.SECTION_ID <> c.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID INSERTFLAG' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID
WHERE a.PART_KIT_ID IS NULL
) b
```

Table definitions:

> -- Script was generated by Devart dbForge Studio for MySQL, Version 6.3.358.0
>   -- Product home page: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio
>   -- Script date 2/9/2016 10:32:41 AM
>   -- Server version: 5.6.21
>
> ### -- Client version: 4.1

```
USE test_kg;

CREATE TABLE cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat (
CTLG_VER_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
CTLG_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EQUIP_MDL_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EQUIPMENT_TECHNOLOGY_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EQUIP_MDL varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
SECTION_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
ACAT_SECTION_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
SECTION_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PART_KIT_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
ACAT_PART_KIT_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
MODULE_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
MODULE_DRIVER_IND varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PART_KIT_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
INDEX IDX_cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat (EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID, PART_KIT_ID,   EQUIP_MDL_ID)
 )
ENGINE = INNODB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 170
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam (
CTLG_VER_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
CTLG_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EQUIP_MDL_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EQUIP_MDL varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
SECTION_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
SECTION_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PART_KIT_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
MODULE_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
MODULE_DRIVER_IND varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PART_KIT_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
UPDATED_DT varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
UPDATE_STATUS varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
INDEX IDX_cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior (EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID, PART_KIT_ID, EQUIP_MDL_ID)
 )
ENGINE = INNODB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 170
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior (
CTLG_VER_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
CTLG_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EQUIP_MDL_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EQUIP_MDL varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
SECTION_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
SECTION_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PART_KIT_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
MODULE_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
MODULE_DRIVER_IND varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PART_KIT_NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
UPDATED_DT varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
UPDATE_STATUS varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
INDEX IDX_cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam (EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID, PART_KIT_ID, EQUIP_MDL_ID)
  )
 ENGINE = INNODB
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 167
 CHARACTER SET latin1
 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: Table definition would be useful helping out with that beautiful query :)

Comment: @Alfabravo - sorry, truly a newb here - I do most of my database activitity in dbForge Studio for MySQL. If I generate the create script for the 3 tables, would that provide the table definition (so, column names/details, engine, avg row length, character set etc)?

Comment: Checking docs, the way to generate DDL for your objects is [here](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/docs/how_to_generate_ddl_statements_for_database_objects.htm).

Comment: Thanks, added table definition :)

Comment: @Alfabravo - I *think* I'm just missing some sort of method of joining the two subqueries, or maybe I should be nesting these instead of... oh, i don't even know, lol. I know I'm close - I just don't know how to get these guys to work together now. They work separately, but I want them to run together in one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck. That was some crash course in subqueries - and i'm still completely hopeless at this for the most part, and only found my answer after searching for 3 days, ha ha ha (and 3 days of trial and error). It would appear that my solution involved not in using multiple subqueries, but taking my two subqueries and writing one big long subquery. If there is a more elegant/efficient/more betterer way of doing this, I will happily unanswer my question and give the answer check mark to someone else!

```
SELECT a.PART_KIT_ID, `Flag NameA`, `Flag NameB`, `PART_KIT_NAME`, `EQUIP_MDL`, `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`, `PART_KIT_DESC`
from (SELECT c.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID` 
, CASE WHEN b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> c.EQUIP_MDL_ID and b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> a.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID FLAG A' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID and b.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> a.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID FLAG B' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID  and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = b.EQUIP_MDL_ID
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = c.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = d.PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID` 
, CASE WHEN a.EQUIP_MDL_ID <> c.EQUIP_MDL_ID THEN 'EQUIP_MDL_ID INSERTFLAG' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, NULL as `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID` 
, CASE WHEN b.SECTION_ID <> c.SECTION_ID and b.SECTION_ID <> a.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID FLAGA' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, CASE WHEN b.SECTION_ID = c.SECTION_ID and b.SECTION_ID <> a.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID FLAGB' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam b ON a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = b.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = b.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = b.EQUIP_MDL_ID
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = c.PART_KIT_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.PART_KIT_ID = d.PART_KIT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.PART_KIT_ID `PART_KIT_ID` 
, CASE WHEN a.SECTION_ID <> c.SECTION_ID THEN 'SECTION_ID INSERTFLAG' ELSE NULL END AS `Flag NameA`
, NULL as `Flag NameB`
, a.PART_KIT_NAME `PART_KIT_NAME`
, a.EQUIP_MDL `EQUIP_MDL`
, a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID `EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID`
, d.PART_KIT_DESC `PART_KIT_DESC`
FROM cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_acat a
JOIN cost_equip_mdl_part_ctlg_icam_prior c on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = c.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID and a.EQUIP_MDL_ID = c.EQUIP_MDL_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN acat_attribute d on a.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID = d.EXTERNAL_SYS_PART_ID
WHERE a.PART_KIT_ID IS NULL
) A
```